# Can't persist entity with multiple entity manager Doctrine

Tags: symfony, security, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I follow this manual to configure my multiple entity manager: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

When I try to persist with my "customer" entity manager, it works.

The authenticate layer works fine, I can login/signup, I use "customer" entity manager (I follow this manual, to get user by uuid or email https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#security-entity-user-provider)

When I try to persist with my "default" entity manager, I get this error:

```
  Class 'App\\Entity\\Cas\\Client' was not found in namespaces configured in string App\\Entity\\Main.
```

I think it's because when I authenticate the user on my API, the entity that's used to do that is Client, and it's handled only by my client entity manager.

I don't know how to handle this problem, because if I cast $security->getUser() to type User, I can't persist with client entity manager.

Anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Might help to update your question with the ORM section of doctrine.yaml.  However each entity manager is an independent silo.  Can't manage an entity with one manager and expect another manager to know about it.  Furthermore, due to a rather strange design decision involving the ServiceEntityRepository class, a given entity type can only be mapped to one manager.  So it's basically not possible to have your User entity mapped to two different entity managers.

Comment: So you're telling me that Symfony adds a feature to use multiple DB and handler, and this feature doesn't work with a containing API working with authentication?

Comment: That is not exactly what I said.  I just explained how the entity managers work and some of the limitations.   There are plenty of ways to authenticate that work just fine.